# The phrase "caught flat footed"...is that okay to use in professional lanuage?

Tags: slang

We are redoing our company website and we are discussing interview tips.

The phrase "caught flat-footed" came up and it sounds a bit derogatory to me.

Is it okay to use in a professional situation? Or is it slang?

Comment: I'd say it's on the informal (not derogatory) side. Why risk it?

Comment: Why not an obvious alternative like "caught unawares"?